# KWin - Modifying the Task Switcher to raise all windows

Tags: kde, application-switcher, kwin

(Apologies in advance if this question is too vague)

I'm attempting to modify the behavior of KWin's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> task switcher. A common situation: I'm working with an application that has several windows open at once. When I switch applications with the task switcher, only the most recent window is raised; to make the others visible, I'll need to manually cycle through them one-by-one to bring each to the front.

I'd like to change this, so the task switcher automatically raises all the application's windows. My current solution is to map <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to the following script:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/bash
oldactive=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
qdbus \
    org.kde.kglobalaccel \
    /component/kwin \
    org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut "Walk Through Windows"
while true; do
    currentactive=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
    if [[ "$oldactive" != "$currentactive" ]]; then
        qdbus org.kde.KWin /Scripting org.kde.kwin.Scripting.loadScript "/home/user/kwinscript"
        qdbus org.kde.KWin /Scripting org.kde.kwin.Scripting.start
        break
    fi
done
```

where `kwinscript` contains the following:

```js
var allClients = workspace.clientList();
var activeClient = workspace.activeClient;

for (i=0; i<allClients.length; i++) {
    if (allClients[i].resourceClass == activeClient.resourceClass) {
        workspace.activeClient = allClients[i];
    }
}

workspace.activeClient = activeClient; //make sure last-used client still ends up on top
```

In short, I'm calling the task switcher with `qdbus`, waiting for it to activate a new window, then calling my script to raise the others. I've re-mapped the actual shortcut for the task switcher itself to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, so it still cycles through applications with Tab and exits when Alt is released.

My question, basically, is: **Is there a better way to do this?**

My solution (mostly) works well enough, but it feels a bit hack-y, and it *seems* like there should be a simpler way. There's also a slight delay (maybe a quarter- to a half-second) between the task switcher exiting and the other windows reappearing, so it would be nice if I could find a solution that runs a little smoother.

---

System Info: Ubuntu 19.10 (*not* Kubuntu), KDE Plasma 5.17.5

Comment: I don't know. Maybe a tiling window manager may offer that feature? There are tiling scripts for KWin as well.

Comment: Eh, I've tried tiling managers, but I largely prefer KWin (sans-tiling). It's really just this one problem that's bugging me; I'm pretty happy with everything else as-is, so I rather not deal with switching window managers altogether if I can avoid it.